# If a bijection $\Bbb{Z}\to\Bbb{Z}^2$ is restricted to $g: \Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{N}\times I_k\subset\Bbb{N} $, is g bijective?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

The question is :

> Show that $f:\mathbb{N} \times I_k\to \Bbb{N}$ defined by
>   $$f(n,i)= (i-1)n+k$$
>   is bijective.
>
> Note: $I_k$ refers to $\{1,2,3,...,k\}$.

Hi, this is a question in my PSET. I am trying to argue that if the inverse of the division algorithm or the Euclid’s division lemma is the function defined above then it is bijective since the division algorithm is a function as well with $n-1$ and $i$ as the output and  $f(n-1)$ or the dividend as the input . However, the inverse of the division algorithm or Euclid’s division lemma must still be defined by the same sets but now $\Bbb{Z}^2\to\Bbb{Z}$ for it to be clearly bijective . If I restrict the sets in the definition of Euclid's division lemma, i.e., $\Bbb{Z}\to\Bbb{Z}^2$, into say function 
$g: \Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{N}\times I_k\subset\Bbb{N} $
is it still bijective ?

If  bijection $\Bbb{Z}\to\Bbb{Z}^2$ is restricted to $g: \Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{N}\times I_k\subset\Bbb{N} $, is g bijective?

Comment: PLease see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: I apologize. I’ll edit once I get my hand on a laptop.

Comment: I've tried to fix your title as well as the MathJax in your question. I hope I didn't get anything (too) wrong. Feel free to edit yourself as you want, of course.

Comment: But this looks a lot like your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3217713/show-that-the-cartesian-product-of-bbbn-and-i-k-is-countably-infinite)... It would have been better to edit the old one to add the context.

Comment: Also, your title looks quite unrelated to your question.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yes indeed it is a continuation of my previous question but more of a doubt to the answer by someone who replied.